# Bootstrap 3 responsive table code replacement in Wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I'm working with bootstrap and wordpress integration.

There are existing posts with `<table>` prior to bootstrap integration.

To make sure of Bootstrap's component, I would like to add wrapper and classes to replace existing table tags from all existing posts:

`<table>...</table>`

to

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">...</table>
</div>
```

Is there a function or filter I can implement to do this code injection globally in my custom theme's `functions.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick filter you can use in functions.php, not sure it is the best approach but will do the trick:

```
    function wp_bootstrap_responsive_table( $content ) {  
        $content = str_replace( ['<table>', '</table>'], ['<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered table-hover">', '</table></div>'], $content );

        return $content;  
    }  
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_bootstrap_responsive_table' );
```

Comment: This does not work and will end up breaking content. WordPress will strip the opening `<div class="table-responsive">` but leave the closing `</div>`, breaking design layouts.